# Tkinter window not clearing the multiple entry field after switch

Tags: python, tkinter

"[Original Post] I am trying to use the Radiobuttons to display more input fields after I select a specific option in my tkinter window, but the value of my 'selection' variable always default to 0, and doesn't ever change.[now fixed]

And, in addition to this, I am not sure how to keep updating my tkinter window as I switch between the options. I tried to implement the tkinter update() function, but it also hasn't worked for me yet. Any helpful suggestions will be highly appreciated.[Original Post Ends]"

This is a follow-up to my original post, is there a way to clear up the multiple input fields after I switch between the number of the entries. ie. How do I refresh the tkinter window to keep the number of the entries consistent with my selection?

I posted my demo code below...

```
from tkinter import *
import time

def selection_window():
selection = var.get()

### Debug ###
print("going in...")
print(selection)

if selection == 1:
    Label(master, text="Info").grid(row=0, column=2)

    Label(master, text=" Input:").grid(row=1, column=2)
    e3 = Entry(master)
    e3.grid(row=1, column=3)

    print("going in2...") ### Debug ###

elif selection == 2:

    Label(master, text="Info").grid(row=0, column=2)

    Label(master, text=" Input:").grid(row=1, column=2)
    e3 = Entry(master)
    e3.grid(row=1, column=3)

    #####################################################################
    #####################################################################
    Label(master, text="Info2").grid(row=0, column=4)

    Label(master, text=" Input2:").grid(row=1, column=4)
    e23 = Entry(master)
    e23.grid(row=1, column=5)

    print("going in3...") ### Debug ### 




if __name__ == '__main__':
master = Tk()
master.title('Demo A')


#####################################################################
###  Display - Multiple fields


Label(master, text="More Info").grid(row=0, column=0)

Label(master, text="Type:").grid(row=1, column=0)
e7 = Entry(master)
e7.grid(row=1, column=1)


#####################################################################
#####################################################################

Button(master, text='Quit', command=master.quit).grid(row=30, column=0, sticky=W, pady=10)
#####################################################################
#####################################################################
var = IntVar()
Label(master, text="Select options").grid(row=33, column=0, sticky=W)
Radiobutton(master, text="1", variable=var, value=1).grid(row=33, column=1, sticky=W)
Radiobutton(master, text="2", variable=var, value=2).grid(row=33, column=2, sticky=W)
Button(master, text="Options+", command=selection_window).grid(row=34, column=0, sticky=W, pady=10)



master.geometry("640x360")

#####################################################################
## Update window
#####################################################################

master.mainloop()
time.sleep(0.1)

### other method to update window(NOT WORKING)
# master.update_idletasks()
# master.update()
```

Comment: Please, indent your code correctly.

Comment: Your `selection_window()` function doesn't return anything. Maybe `return selection` ?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille  I tried returning selection, still hasn't worked..

Comment: You are getting zero becuse of _not passing the reference of function_ issue. Also, about updating, check out radiobutton's command option.

Comment: @Lafexlos Could you please explain what you mean, I quite didn't understand "not passing the reference of function issue" ...

Comment: That link I provided above explains it. First couple sentences of first answer explains that.

Comment: @Lafexlos Thanks.. I understand what you said, but there is a small problem still when I switch between 2 and 1, the second input field still stays .. Could you suggest a fix for that? Is there a way to clear and refresh the window everytime after I switch?